# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (96)

Tags: numpy, reshape, shapes, broadcast, dimension

I have an array of shape, (4478,)
`print(Customer_Reaction_Array.shape)` -> (4478,)

I want to load/copy the array, `Customer_Reaction_Array` into another array of shape, (4478, 96)
`y=np.zeros([len(Customer_Reaction_Array),Customer_Reaction_Array[0].shape[0]]) print (y.shape)` -> (4478, 96)

It can load the array up to the index, y[455,:] = Customer_Reaction_Array[455]
Then I got the error, `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (96)`

My code is:

```
for i in range(len(Customer_Reaction_Array)):
    y[i,:] = Customer_Reaction_Array[i]
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem completely but if you want to copy an existing array along a new axis, then use

```py
initial_dimension = Customer_Reaction_Array.shape
second_dimension = 96

y = np.repeat(Customer_Reaction_Array, second_dimension).reshape(*initial_dimension, second_dimension)
```

you can check `y.T` to get the transpose of that array in case you need it oriented that way